# Rename all folders in a directory

Tags: java, android

I need help in renaming all files and folders in a directory and add a character in front of there original name.

This is a method to rename a single folder:

```
File from = new File(sdcard,".DCIM");
File to = new File(sdcard,"DCIM");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, something like:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/MyDir";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File f = new File(path);        
File file[] = f.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
{
    file[i].renameTo(file[i].getName() + "x");
}
```

EDIT:

To change a file name, it might be more clear to add a temporary variable:

```
    String name = file[i].getName();
    name = name.substr(0, name.length() - 1);
    file[i].renameTo(name);
```

Comment: In this case i think it will go only in one directory if any inner directory is there then we have to make call again to the same function.

Comment: Yes - I did not account for nested directories, although it isn't clear the OP needs that. Also, it should be fairly trivial to implement by making this a method with a directory name being passed in...

Comment: This worked thanks put do you have any idea on how to restore the files to there original names, or just delete the first character in there names???

Comment: I made an edit for renaming. For restoration you will need a different approach - depending on how you want the names restored; Android apps can have a phone call interrupt your process, so knowing the expected stability and use case really makes that a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.Just one more question, name = name.substring(0, name.length() - 1);  this deletes the last character of the folder,i want to delete the first character any idea how?

Comment: Yes - name = name.substring(1, name.length()) - but you prob figured that out by now

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root folder and iterate over it. Just check if the the folder you are accessing is a directory or not and you can write the same logic in between for every folder.

```
public static void renameFile(String path) throws IOException {

        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();

        if (list == null)
            return;

        for (File f : list) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {

                File from = new File(f,"."+f.getName());
                File to = new File(f,f.getName());
                from.renameTo(to);
                renameFile(f.getCanonicalPath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //Root path within which you want to change the folder names
        renameFile("c:\rootPath");
    }
```

Just check if this helps you.